# Gtk and C - Multi-threaded GUI Application and Removing Global Variables

Tags: c, gtk, pthreads

I have the example GTK C application from [1] building and working as expected. I have a pretty little UI application with a `+` and `-` button to increment/decrement a value stored in a global variable, and render it in the application in a text label.

I rarely ever work with GUI applications, and I do 99% of my work in C. I have two key questions with respect to tidying up this example and using it as the basis of a project.

- Is it possible to have some alternative to global variables, like a
  custom `struct` I create in `main()`, and have every callback handler reference
  it by changing the function protocol for `increase()`?

Code:

```
// Can this function protocol be modified?
void increase(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer label) {
  count++;
  sprintf(buf, "%d", count);
  gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(label), buf);
}
g_signal_connect(minus, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(decrease), label);
```

- Is there a simple means of creating a separate thread to help manage the GUI? For example, if I have a button tied/connected to a function that would take a minute to complete, is there a universally-accepted means of firing off a separate `pthread` that allows me to have a button or command to cancel the operation, rather than the entire UI app being blocked for the whole minute?

Thank you.

**References**

---

1. *Cross Compiling GTK applications For the Raspberry Pi*, Accessed 2014-02-20, `<http://hertaville.com/2013/07/19/cross-compiling-gtk-applications-for-the-raspberry-pi/>`

Comment: It turns out the `label` parameter was the extra data pointer. I just created a pointer-to-struct to use instead of `label`, and changed the function protocol to `void increase(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer myStruct_t)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass anything you like as the last argument to signal handlers (gpointer is a typedef for void*) just create the structure containing the label widget and the counter variable in `main()`, pass it as the last argument to `g_signal_connect` and cast it back to the proper type in your callback.

For running a calculation in another thread and delivering the result to the gtk main loop I'd look at [GTask](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GTask.html), in particular [g_task_run_in_thread_async](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GTask.html#g-task-run-in-thread-sync).